# Unknown url type error in urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2, ubuntu-14.04

I have searched a lot of similar question on SO, but did not find an exact match to my case.

I am trying to download a video using python 2.7

Here is my code for downloading the video

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


with open('video.txt','r') as f:
    last_downloaded_video = f.read()

webpage = urllib2.urlopen('http://*.net/watch/**-'+last_downloaded_video)

soup = bs(webpage)
a = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('data-video-id'):
        a.append(link)

#try just with first data-video-id

id = a[0]['data-video-id']
webpage2 = urllib2.urlopen('http://*/video/play/'+id)
soup = bs(webpage2)
string = str(soup.find_all('script')[2])
print string
url = string.split(': ')[1].split(',')[0]
url = url.replace('"','')
print url
print type(url)

video = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
filename = "video.mp4"
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    f.write(video)
```

This code gives an unknown url type error. The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "naruto.py", line 26, in <module>
    video = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 427, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1247, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 'http>
```

However, when i store the same url in a variable and attempt to download it from terminal, no error is shown.
I am confused as to what the problem is.
I got a similar question [in python mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-June/539695.html)

Comment: What is the output of your `print url` statement? What is `url[0]`? It seems that it is "'http" (note extra single quote at the beginning of the string), in which case you need to remove that from the URL. It might be easier if you supply the actual URL that you are using.

Comment: print url gives 'http:// oose.io/20a6b47da772361b05d1c4ad3cf1723a5209d0cc/video.mp4' (a link to naruto episode, working fine)

Comment: I have deliberately given a space after // since the http was not being displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the HTML from the page that you are scraping, however, a stray `'` (single quote) character at the beginning of the URL might be the cause - this causes the same exception:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen("'http://blah.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "urllib2.py", line 427, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "urllib2.py", line 1249, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 'http>
```

So, try cleaning up your URL and remove any stray quotes.

**Update after OP feedback:**

The results of the print statement indicate that the URL has a *single quote* character at the beginning and end of the URL string. There should not *any* quotes of any type surrounding the URL when it is passed to `urlopen()`. You can remove leading and trailing quotes (both single and double) from the URL string with this:

```
url = url.strip('\'"')
```

Comment: I thought that this might be the reason and so i printed the url before fetching it the url prints 'http:// oose.io/20a6b47da772361b05d1c4ad3cf1723a5209d0cc/video.mp4'

Comment: Does it make a difference if the url is surrounded by single or double quotes?

Comment: @rahulmr : answer updated - you need to remove the surrounding single quotes from the url string.

Comment: Thanks, i had done a workaround like url[1:][:-1]. But i am a little confused. When i pass the url surrounded in quotes in terminal , why is that not wrong?

Comment: Surrounding quotes are removed by the shell as part of the command processing, so the command does not see the additional quotes. In your Python program it looks like you are extracting the URL from some blob of javascript, but you are not removing the surrounding single quotes (you do seem to remove double quotes). Since you are trying to process javascript, you might be able to use json.loads(string) to get a convenient Python object - hard to say for sure without seeing the javascript.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the json.loads(string). I will certainly try to implement it.